# Gmail: Change automated functions

Tags: gmail

I don't know how to stop Gmail from dropping seen/read emails to the bottom of the screen. I don't want those emails to move from where they are in the "received" list. Rather, I just want to organise this thing so emails come in chronologically, and messages stay put regardless of if they're read or unread. I just discovered an email that had come in October 3rd, which I briefly saw but "lost" not realising it had somehow been moved to the very bottom of my inbox.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I only see messages drift towards the bottom if newer messages come in. Are you using any addons?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE.  Please take the [Tour] and review [ask].  Then [edit] your question to indicate whether you are using Gmail on a mobile device or a desktop/laptop.  Also, indicate what your Inbox type is set to under **Quick Settings** (see [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD0fL.png "Quick Settings")) or under **[Settings > Inbox > Inbox type](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/inbox "mail.google.com/mail/#settings/inbox")**  (See [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w1Sm.png "Inbox Type menu"))

Answer (score 1):

If you click the "gear" (⚙) icon in the top right of Gmail to open the quick settings pane, there's a section labeled "Inbox type" that you can use to choose which order of emails you prefer. The "default" (which I use) is chronological as far as I can tell.

[image: Screenshot of Gmail's inbox type settings]